# Swift String's count property time complexity

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm wondering about what the time complexity of Swift (Swift 5) String's count property is? I found it is very slow.

I guess it's O(n), linear time complexity, but cannot find any document about it. Can any one help?

I made a little test about it, compared with Array's count property which is way more faster.

Test result on my machine:

Test Case '-[TESTS.TESTS testArrayCountPerformance]' passed (1.686 seconds).

Test Case '-[TESTS.TESTS testStringCountPerformance]' passed (11.113 seconds).

```
class TESTS: XCTestCase {

    let letters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")

    var randomString = ""
    var randomChars: [Character] = []

    override func setUp() {
        for _ in 0..<1000000 {
            randomString += String(letters[Int.random(in: 0..<letters.count)])
        }
        randomChars = Array(randomString)
    }

    func testStringCountPerformance() {
        measure {
            for _ in 0..<100 {
                _ = randomString.count
            }
        }
    }

    func testArrayCountPerformance() {
        measure {
            for _ in 0..<100 {
                _ = randomChars.count
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`. `String` conforms to `BidirectionalCollection`. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) for the `Collection` protocol you'll find this:

> The performance of some collection operations depends on the type of
>   index that the collection provides. For example, a random-access
>   collection, which can measure the distance between two indices in O(1)
>   time, can calculate its count property in O(1) time. Conversely,
>   because a forward or bidirectional collection must traverse the entire
>   collection to count the number of contained elements, accessing its
>   count property is an O(n) operation.

So, you can expect `String.count` to be more computationally expensive than `Array.count`.